# Occupancy grid map from zed stereo camera

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create 2d Occupancy grid from zed stereo camera .I referred  this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping for doing so.But I am unable recreate it since here its given from bumblebee2 stereo camera to OGM.Also it subscribe to these topics:
1]/stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle/compressed
2]/stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle/compressed
3]/stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle
4]/stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle
5]/tf

which i dont know how to publish or record using bag file from standalone stereo camera.
Please suggest me how to implement this or any other way to implement the problem statement.I request you guys to give detailed procedure since I am novice to ROS and robotics

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266645/occupancy-grid-map-from-zed-stereo-camera/) by [ankursingh0820](https://answers.ros.org/users/31244/ankursingh0820/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I think basically you are asking you need to publish the same topics from ZED as it is being published by Bumbelbee2? If yes

You need to install the ZED ros package as mentioned in the below link.

http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper

Once you do it you need to launch the ZED camera launch file by this command
roslaunch zed_wrapper zed.launch

After this launch the following topics will be published :

```
/zed/confidence/confidence_image
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressed
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/theora
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/confidence/confidence_image/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/confidence/confidence_map
/zed/depth/camera_info
/zed/depth/depth_registered
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressed
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/depth/depth_registered/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/depth/depth_registered/theora
/zed/depth/depth_registered/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/depth/depth_registered/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/disparity/disparity_image
/zed/joint_states
/zed/left/camera_info
/zed/left/camera_info_raw
/zed/left/image_raw_color
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressed
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/left/image_raw_color/theora
/zed/left/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/left/image_rect_color
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressed
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/left/image_rect_color/theora
/zed/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/left/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/map
/zed/odom
/zed/point_cloud/cloud_registered
/zed/rgb/camera_info
/zed/rgb/camera_info_raw
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/theora
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/theora
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/rgb/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/right/camera_info
/zed/right/camera_info_raw
/zed/right/image_raw_color
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressed
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_raw_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/right/image_raw_color/theora
/zed/right/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_raw_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/right/image_rect_color
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressed
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressed/parameter_updates
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_rect_color/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/zed/right/image_rect_color/theora
/zed/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_descriptions
/zed/right/image_rect_color/theora/parameter_updates
/zed/zed_wrapper_node/parameter_descriptions
/zed/zed_wrapper_node/parameter_updates
```

From this list you can easily get the topics you are looking for. One you figure that out you can modify the subscriber in the Grid Map package to subscribe the new topics. I think after this you will be good to go...

All the best!!!!

Regards,
Saptarshi

---

Originally posted by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) with karma: 180 on 2018-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2018-07-20**:
Please don't forget to upvote if this works and feel free to ask anything more specific to this......